# How to periodically fetch/update value in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller

Let's take a scenario:

```
counter 10 seconds
```

- User visited `show.html.erb` page
- `show.html.erb` fetch the value from `database` using `<%= @post.value %>`.
- Counter started and each iteration of counter is for `10 seconds`.
- After every `10 seconds` I wanted to change the `@post.value` using `utility` class.
- update the `@post.value` in database.
- Refresh the `show.html.erb` automatically and `<%= @post.value %>` will show the updated value
- Above process will be run in loop until user move to other pages.

If I have to simplify the problem in code then it would like this:

## View Page

```
<%= @post.value %>
<%= @post.name %>
```

## Controller Method

```
def show
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def update
....   #It's empty right now
end

def fetching_value_from_PostUpdate(current_value)
 .. # Now I need to update the value in database
end
```

## Utility class

I want to update the `post.value` on the basis of method written in this class. Pseudo code:

```
class PostUpdate
 @@instance_variable   

 def initialize(post_value)
   @@instance_variable = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(post_value))
 end

  #Method required to calculate the value
def update_data_in_database
 ...
return data
end
```

Questions

- Where do I have to put the counter? client side or server side? I don't want to use `background jobs` in rails.
- What changes do I need to make in `show` method so that after every interval page will refresh automatically and pass the updated value in `@post.value`?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you might get better answers if you describe what is you are actually trying to do - are you trying to add a view counter? Or provide some form of live updates? Try to describe it from users standpoint.

Comment: @AmitPal : Question 2 and 3 are confusing, are you thinking of either of them or both? If you refresh the page periodically every 10 seconds then updating a particular value using ajax doesn't make sense. Also, you can not update `<%= @post.value %>`'s value on view, you can update the HTML fragment where that value is rendered on page. Is that what you're trying to say? am I missing something?

Comment: @Surya  Yes, I am thinking one of them or any approach which is better.  Yes you are correct about `HTML` rendering.

I haven't think about that `Ajax` is not going to work in this case.

Ultimately I am looking for a way thorugh which I can updates the `post.value` periodically (as per conunter) using given `utility` class method till user is visiting the page. 

Let's say @ first visit : counter start and `@post.value` = 3
update the value in database and render the new value in HTML view after refreshing the page automatically
Wait for 10 seconds and continue the above proecss

Answer (score 2):

I would go with [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) as opposed to polling the server.

However, if you're wanting to poll the server periodically, I would just have a JavaScript method which executes every 10 seconds, or at whatever interval you'd like, and fetches whatever data you'd like asynchronously and subsequently updates the DOM.

Also, [ruby wrapper for firebase api](https://github.com/oscardelben/firebase-ruby), in case that may be of interest

Answer (score 1):

I would say the easiest approach doing it would be using [ActionController::Live](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Live.html). Using it you'll be able to send SSE(Server Sent Event) to your client while having js script there to catch and update your `<%= @post.value %>`. Here's a [pretty nice manual](http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/07/30/is-it-live.html) on using it.

Still from my point of view the most appropriate way to implement things you want to do will be using something like [Faye](http://faye.jcoglan.com/). It is a publish/subscribe messaging system which will allow you to update your client with new data as soon as it appears, e.g., you can set an `after_save` in your model and publish an update to all subscribed clients. And of course there is a gem also called [faye](https://github.com/faye/faye) to wrap its usage.